# 32bit ODBC Postgres driver on Windows 2008 R2 x64

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, postgresql, odbc

I'm trying to install the Postgres ODBC 32bit driver on a Windows 2008 R2 64bit machine. After installing it, with no errors, I go to the ODBC panel, the 32bit version under the /syswow64 folder and try to add the driver, select the Postgres driver from the list but I get an error 126, saying he can't find the driver at the specified path.

The problem is that the path he shows me, is the exact path the driver is in, I double checked on the registery (on the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ location) and it's fine there too.
A couple more people on [technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2f9ff7c6-6867-4d08-a2a2-74cba69b18f2/odbc-administrator-32bit-syswow64odbc32adexe-fails-on-system-dsn-add-with-error-code-126?forum=winservercore&prof=required) have the same issue too.

Did anyone ever run into this? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

edit: the driver works fine on my win7 x64 test machine, this behaviour only happens on the server.

Comment: Can you fire up a brand new 2008 R2 and try to replicate the problem?

Comment: Unsure if our license allows for that, I'll check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. Leaving the answer here and a couple other places for future generations:

The system was missing the "secret" prerequisite of having [Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable x86](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) installed (not the x64, that one it had). Fixed the problem instantly.

Comment: I found today that you do need both the x64 version of the vs2010 redistributable if you want to install the x64 version of the odbc driver.